# Table inside the div tag is overflowing to outside of the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I want keep the table inside `div` tag but half of the last section is missing. 
This is my html structure that I have used,

```css
 .dataTable{
     table-layout: fixed;         
    }
    .dataTable td{     
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="dataTable">
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Issue what I have faced
[image]

Can anyone help me to slove this issue?

Comment: try removing `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: try removing overflow:hidden; thought it will add a scroll bar at the bottom, if  you do not want that then reduce the width of one of the columns

Comment: Try to provide jsfiddle link for this.

Comment: when I remove `overflow: hidden;' it goes over other `td` s

Comment: @karthika I will add a jsfiddle link

Comment: Data you have in your question isn't the same amount of data used in the image. 3 cols instead of 5. Can you create a working fiddle with the issue? This is what I'm getting https://jsfiddle.net/gkktq81t/1/

Comment: `.dataTable td {
display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;}`
This code works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.dataTable{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;            
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#YourTable').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
                 });
        });
```